# Why is VBA macro opening the file it was copied from, not the sheet in the current workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I copied all macros from Module 1 in one file to Module 1 another, including this one:

```
Sub OpenMonth4tabs()
 '
' OpenMonth4tabs Macro
' Closes all sheets except Base Values
' Opens sheets for Month 4, prepares Base Data for month 4 view
'
 Call HideAllSheets
 Call PrepareMonth4Base

Sheets("M4 Sales Record").Visible = True
Sheets("M4 Sales Record").Select
Sheets("M4 P&L").Visible = True
Sheets("M4 P&L").Select
Sheets("M4 Sales KPIs").Visible = True
Sheets("M4 Sales KPIs").Select
Sheets("M4 Aftersales KPIs").Visible = True
Sheets("M4 Checklist").Visible = True
Sheets("M4 Checklist").Select
Range("C10").Select

End Sub
```

However, although the file I am working in has tabs with the exact names as the original (it is a later version with a similar name), when it runs it opens the original file and tabs, not the tabs in the current workbook. I can't see anything in the code that identifies the original workbook, and don't know how to prevent this.

What is the reason the code is referring to another, closed workbook?
How can I get it to work within the new workbook, and not open the old one?
Any help will be greatly appreciated, it is driving me nuts!

Comment: what's in `HideAllSheets` and `PrepareMonth4Base` subs? maybe they activate the "old" workbook and so the not fully qualified worksheets references point to that "old" workbook ones

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the suggestions, from which I have learnt. In the meantime, a colleague found the root of the problem:
The macros were working perfectly, but I also copied across a worksheet with buttons linked to macros, and the links were specifically to the macros in the old workbook, not the current one. So each time I used a button to run a macro, it opened the old worksheet and ran the macro on it. If I ran the macro from the macro box, it worked in the new (currently active) workbook without opening the old one.
So the question I asked was the wrong question, but I now see how to solve the problem, by re-linking the control buttons to the correct workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add an active workbook reference at the beginning of the macro and then use that to preface the Sheets references.   Something like:

```
dim wb as workbook
set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Call HideAllSheets
Call PrepareMonth4Base

wb.worksheets("M4 Sales Record").Visible = True
wb.worksheets("M4 Sales Record").Select
etc
```